# Showing $\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln\Bigg(\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{j}{n}}\Bigg)=\int_{1}^{2} \ln(x)$

Tags: integration, analysis

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln\Bigg(\prod_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{j}{n}}\Bigg)=\int_{1}^{2} \ln(x)$$

How can I prove this? (Preferably using the definitions of integrals/upper sums/lower sums.)

Comment: I looked at $\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{j}{n}}$ for $n=j=1$ which gives 2 and then for $n \to \infty$ which gives 1.

The hint was that the limit is equal to the integral of $\ln(x)$ in an appropriate interval so I chose from $x=1$ to $x=2$ which seems to be correct but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Use the fact that it is a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
\begin{align}
\ln  \left( \prod_{j=1}^n \sqrt[n]{1+\frac{j}{n}} \right)
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \ln  \left(1+\frac{j}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}
= \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \ln\left(1+\frac{j}{n}\right).
\end{align}